# Kendo UI Tooltip Bugs

Tags: tooltip, kendo-ui

I have few bugs while using the tooltip from KENDO UI. I wanted to show help message for my input fields and so I set the position of tooltip to the right but it shows towards the top right corner of the input field. 
Moreover when I bring the mouse over the input field the title of the page changes. 
If I am setting 
    autoClose: false 
then there are 2 X buttons in the tooltip.

Sample markup and javascripts

```
<input type="text" title="Please enter firstname." id="txtFirstname" />

    $("#txtFirstname").kendoTooltip({
        autoHide: false,
        callout: false,
        showOn: "focus",
        position:"right"
    });
```

Please help to fix these bugs

Thanks
Prabhanjan

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your issue in Kendo Dojo/below link.
http://try.kendoui.com/

Comment: I haven't tried with dojo. will try and let you know.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBfk2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think those issues were addressed in [Q1 2013 SP1 (version 2013.1.514) - May 2013](http://www.kendoui.com/web/whats-new/release-notes/q1-2013-sp1.aspx) release.

Here are release notes about tooltip of that release:

Fixed: Document title is removed when tooltip is open
Fixed: Tooltip content is not cleared when its title attribute is missing and it
    was shown for another target

Have you tried to use new version?